# Make sure only one instances of Tomcat runs

Tags: java, tomcat

I have a web application running on tomcat 5.5 which starts about 100 (still growing) threads every minute to collect the data from the sensors and upload it into the database.I am using `ScheduledExecutorService`

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduler = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1);
scheduler.scheduleAtFixedRate(uploader, 0, 60 , TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

I am facing a weird problem here, sometimes tomcat starts multiple instances itself and collect the same data for the same sensor (I do have a check to not upload the data if it is already in the database). I am not sure what is the problem here. Is it the threads or the instances of tomcat? Any ideas what might be the problem?

Comment: Multiple instances of the Tomcat web container as in multiple processes? Or multiple instances of the webapplication? How did you detect the problem? Note that if a scheduled task would take longer than 60 seconds to complete, subsequent tasks may be delayed.

Comment: maybe this topic should be concurrency - or thread safe data collection  instead.